# Java replace all occurences of regex with another regex

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string with an xml many occurences of `<tagA>`:

```
String example = " (...) some xml here (...)
                    <tagA>283940</tagA>
                   (...) some xml here (...)
                    <tagA>& 9940</tagA>
                    <tagA>- 99440</tagA>
                    <tagA>< 99440</tagA>
                    <tagA>99440</tagA>
                   (...) more xml here (...) "
```

The  content should contain only digits, but sometimes it has a random character followed by a whitespace and the the digits. 
I want to remove the unwanted character and the whitespace. How to do that?

So far I know I should be looking for a regex `"<tagA>. [0-9]*<\/tagA>"` but I am stuck here.

**I want to replace the characters because among those characters there are "&", ">", "<" signs which make the xml invalid (which prevents me from treating this as an XML).**

Comment: [Do not use regular expressions to parse XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: Use XPath and the `starts-with` function in the predicate.

Comment: I cannot parse XML because it is not valid. (The ampersand character makes the xml invalid)

Comment: You can replace all & occurrences with something else before parsing it. Or URL-Encode the file.

Comment: @AlexRoig there are & occurences in other places of the string (inside CDATA) so this has to be in the tagA tag

Comment: Got it. Let me try to write something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that you're looking for is:
`<(\w+)>(\D{0,})(\d+)`

On the search `Group 1` you'll get the TAG, on the `Group 2` you'll get your weird stuff (everything that is not a digit) and in `Group 3` there's the number.

There's an "enhanced version" of this regex that might work in more situations: `(\w{0,})(<\w+>)(\D{0,})(\d+)(\D{0,})(<\/\w+>)(\w{0,})`

This will place in the `Group 1` any whitespace that might be before the tag. `Group 7` will take care of the trailing whitespaces.
`Group 2 and 6` will match the opening tag and closing tag.
`Group 3 and 5` will match any weird character that you might have between your value.
`Group 4` will contain your value.

With the String::replaceAll, you can filter and sanitize by printing only the group 2, 4 and 6, getting rid of the rest.

```
//input data
String s = "<tagA>283940</tagA>\n" +
"                    <tagA>& 9940<</tagA>\n" +
"                    <tagA>- 99440</tagA>\n" +
"                    <tagA>< 99440</tagA>\n" +
"                    <tagA>99440</tagA>"
                + "<13243> asdfasdf </>";


    String replaced = s.replaceAll("(\\s{0,})(<\\w+>)(\\D{0,})(\\d+)(\\D{0,})(<\\/\\w+>)(\\s{0,})", "$2$4$6");
    System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `<tagA>283940</tagA><tagA>9940</tagA><tagA>99440</tagA><tagA>99440</tagA><tagA>99440</tagA><13243> asdfasdf </>`